# Is there a way in selenium and/or phpunit, to simulate actual physical typing

Tags: angularjs, selenium, autocomplete, phpunit

I am trying to create automated test that involves an angularjs auto-complete.

Since Selenium webdriver is simply assigning values to fields, rather than typing, the drop-down does not populate upon playback.

Is there a way in selenium and/or PHPunit, to simulate actual physical typing (which initiates auto-complete to return suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with WebDriverElement::sendKeys:

```
/**
* Simulate typing into an element, which may set its value.
*
* @param mixed $value The data to be typed.
* @return WebDriverElement The current instance.
*/
public function sendKeys($value);
```

like this:

```
$driver->findElement(\WebDriverBy::id("email"))->sendKeys("user@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I simulate selecting from a dropdown by using a loop to send down arrows once every half second, similar to this pseudo-code :

```
loop {
    sendKeys( Keys.DOWN );
    sleep 0.5
}
```

You could do the same with sending single characters...